# XCode 3.2.5: Deploy Debug Build to iPhone iOS 4.2.1 is FAILING

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, deployment, ios-provisioning

I am having one of those horrible days where absolutely everything is broken.

I'm trying to deploy my application to my iPhone. I have done a full system restore to 4.2.1  on both devices.  The iPhone is simply having none of it:   http://cl.ly/3O1C242k210T2I0w253Q  -- What's going wrong?

Organiser picks the iPhone up no problem,  gives it the green light,   but XCode won't deploy the app: ***'No provisioned iOS device is connected'***

I have tried:

- rebooting the computer,  restarting X code,  plugging in the iPhone,  attempting to deploy.   pretty much every combination thereof.
- organiser ->  deleting and recreating Xcode's default provisioning profile
- target settings ->  making sure the correct provisioning profile is selected which it is
- going onto developer.apple.com -> provisioning portal,  and making sure X code automatic provisioning profile is there as it should be,  which it is
- putting the iPhone in to restore mode,  and reinstalling the latest iOS

The only thing I can think of is that it is a UK locked phone,  with a UK SIM inside,  and when I turn it on it gives me some ' waiting for activation ' message: http://cl.ly/0I390x2Z3E3A040V2J2h  so maybe it is possible that it never activates and this is somehow a barrier. can anyone confirm?

( I doubt it is this;  I'm pretty sure the phone is capable of activating itself even tho I'm not in the UK,  seeing as I have the correct SIM card in.  I remember one time reinstalling iOS or something similar,  and it needed the activation.   so I think it does successfully activate. However, I don't know how to check whether activation has completed or not. )

But I have successfully deployed a load of apps to this device in the past.   I can't understand why XCode is digging its heels in today?!

PS  the only other thing I can think of Short of buying new hardware is reinstalling Xcode,  which I guess I will have to try at some point.  maybe even reinstalling my  MacBook's OSX. but really I can't see how this would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on IRC got me to try deploying a default template app,  and that worked.

I subsequently removed and reinstalled the SDK,  and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking your code-sign parameters. Maybe it's signed with app profile that doesn't have your device's UDID added through provisioning profile?